# Script which returns a service name when you give it a service's default port number

Tags: linux, bash, service, port

I need to write a bash script which returns a service name when you give it a service's default port number. I am working with `/etc/services` file. And my code is:

```
grep -E  $1 /etc/services | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

But it's not working with ports like 1,2,3,...20 and some other. How to improve it or maybe I need another solution to solve this?

Comment: Let me explain. You can save this script as portnumber.sh and make it executable making chmod +x portnumber.sh. $1 is user input and it equals port number. For example: ./portnumber.sh 22 you will get ssh. But if you make ./portnumber.sh 20 you will get # but right answer is ftp-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can provide any port_number to `input_port` variable, it will be matched in the first part of 2nd column and if matched 1st column will be printed.

```
    awk -v input_port="$1" '{split($2,a,"/")}input_port==a[1]{print $1}' /etc/services
    smtp
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! Exactly what i need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
getent services 22
```

outputs:

```
ssh                   22/tcp
```

and if you just need the name:

```
getent services 22 | awk '{print $1}'
```

outputs:

```
ssh
```

When querying information on a system, use `getent` whenever possible since some entries may come from sources other than a file in `/etc`. For example, instead of parsing `/etc/passwd` for a user named `USERNAME`, use `getent passwd USERNAME` since the entry might come from LDAP, for example, instead of `/etc/password`.

On my system, `getent` knows about the following "databases":

```
ahosts     ahostsv6   ethers     gshadow    netgroup   passwd     rpc        shadow     
ahostsv4   aliases    group      hosts      networks   protocols  services
```